# To display the objects of an array using loops

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I have array called `addresses` which contains multiple objects inside it (i,e multiple address).

```
[
 {
   "name": "Jhon Doe",
   "gender": "Male",
   "addresses": [
        {
            "addressType": "Home",
            "city": "Portland",
            "country": "United States",
            "postalCode": "97286",
            "state": "Oregon",
            "street": "86807 Twin Pines Way"
        },
        {
            "addressType": "Office",
            "city": "Phoenix",
            "country": "United States",
            "postalCode": "85083",
            "state": "Arizona",
            "street": "0583 Dayton Junction"
        }
    ]
 },
  .
  .
  .
  .
  .
  .
  .
  .
 {
   "name": "Mark Wood",
   "gender": "Male",
   "addresses": [
      {
         "addressType": "Home",
          "city": "Minneapolis",
          "country": "United States",
          "postalCode": "55417",
          "state": "Minnesota",
          "street": "0 School Way"
      },
      {
          "addressType": "Office",
          "city": "Tuscaloosa",
          "country": "United States",
          "postalCode": "35487",
          "state": "Alabama",
           "street": "98 Vernon Place"
      },
      {
          "addressType": "Others",
           "city": "Sacramento",
           "country": "United States",
           "postalCode": "95833",
           "state": "California",
           "street": "40581 Superior Pass"
         }
      ]
    }

  ]
```

**Reference Pic**:

[image]

I want **display all the addresses** depending upon number of objects present(i,e No/Type of address).

> I am able to display the multiple address using the **objects index position**, but i want to display by **looping**.

Stackblitz **[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-movie-read-load-json-sample-eg-4z9qp7?file=src/assets/movies.json)**

Comment: on address `td` you can call inner loop like this.
`<td *ngFor="let cd of contact.addresses">
          {{cd.addressType}}
        </td>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="cust-detail" *ngFor="let contact of contacts">
    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>{{contact.name }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gender</td>
      <td>{{contact.gender}} </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Address</td>
      <td>
        <div *ngFor="let addr of contact.addresses">
            {{addr.street}},
            {{addr.city}},
            {{addr.country}},
            {{addr.state}},
            {{addr.postalCode}} ({{addr.addressType}})
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <hr>
</div>
```

Comment: your solution is working fine, but when i tried with my application ,I am getting this error:  **ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'addresses' of undefined**

Comment: Did you initialize the variable? That might be the problem.

Comment: Ya, I initialized the variable.

Comment: I couldn't see any initializing in demo.

Comment: In DEMO i didn't initialized, I initialized in my `app`.

Comment: Like this? `ngOnInit(){ this.contacts = []; }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186297/discussion-between-empty-soul-and-arcteezy).

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through address:

```
<td *ngFor="let abc of contact.addresses">
    {{abc.addressType}} 
</td>
```

Comment: I am getting this error:  **ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'addresses' of undefined**

Comment: you should wait till your first ngFor loaded. you can wrap it inside ngif e.g:  
`<td *ngIf="contact.addresses != undefined" *ngFor="let abc of contact.addresses">`

Comment: Got this error: **Can't have multiple template bindings on one element**

Comment: try this `*ngIf="contact != undefined"` on your `<tr>` tag of address.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, this is just like the structure you wanted with direct indexing:

```
<tr *ngFor="let eachAddress of contact?.addresses;let i = index">
  <ng-container *ngIf="i === 0; else notFirst"><td>Address</td></ng-container>
  <ng-template #notFirst><td></td></ng-template>
  <td>{{eachAddress?.street}},
      {{eachAddress?.city}},
      {{eachAddress?.country}},
      {{eachAddress?.state}},
      {{eachAddress?.postalCode}} ({{eachAddress?.addressType}})
  </td>
</tr>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-movie-read-load-json-sample-eg-dmhidj?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: I am getting this error:  **ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'addresses' of undefined**

Comment: @Empty_Soul: Are you missing the safe navigation operator (`?`) somewhere in your code?

Comment: @Empty_Soul: You don't  mean that you are getting the error in the Stackblitz example, right?

Comment: I have use safe navigator`(?)` ,Still issue is there.

Comment: I am not getting any errors in **stackblitz**.

Comment: @Empty_Soul: Search for the string "'.addresses'" either in your `HTML` or `.ts` you  will find an instance. If its in `.ts` then you have to do something like: `if (something) then something.addresses`, for "HTML", safe navigation will do